# NSString Arabic encoding from HTML

Tags: ios, objective-c

To extract arabic string from HTML, I use next code

```
NSError *errorReading;
NSURL *urlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileName withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:@"fatawa"];
NSString *fileHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorReading];
```

the app crashed at NSUTF8StringEncoding
when using NSASCIIStringEncoding the arabic didn't get correctly

Comment: Show the stacktrace.  Also what does `file /path/to/fatawa.html` show?

Comment: What is the actual encoding of the html file?

Comment: fileName path is correct when change file has English content the string returned perfectly using NSASCIIStringEncoding

Comment: The Encoding of files is "Windows-1256"